# How to set the area/rectangle in which the cursor is allowed to move?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse-cursor

E.g. when you hit the side of your monitor your cursor can't go any further, and more of an example is when in microsoft paint, and your choosing a colour from the RGB table, it won't allow your mouse to go outside of the rectangle while your mouse is down..

my question is how would you implement that in c++ with win32 api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function from Microsoft

```
BOOL WINAPI ClipCursor(
  __in_opt  const RECT *lpRect
);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Oh, thanks :) I knew it would be simple... just couldn't think what to search on google/msdn.

Comment: Google search on: constrain mouse movement rectangle win32

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ClipCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(VS.85).aspx) function. Simply provide the rectangle to confine the cursor to. To release the mouse (that is, to restore normal behaviour), simply pass NULL to the function instead of a pointer to a rect structure.