# Is there any way in C++ windows code to stop a mouse moving oustide window bounds

Tags: c++, windows, windowed

I had a look and couldn't find any way apart from 3rd party programs. But is there any way through code (C++) that I can stop the cursor from being moved outside the bounds of the window?  I have a FPS Game project on windows but obviously in windowed mode the mouce can be moved outside of the window which can then cause issues.

Comment: did you check out [the msdn article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Confining_a_Cursor)?

Comment: I didn't see that they had one, Thanks I will check it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the area/rectangle in which the cursor is allowed to move?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660709/how-to-set-the-area-rectangle-in-which-the-cursor-is-allowed-to-move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ClipCursor:

```
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);
ClipCursor(&rect);
```

Remember to release che Cursor with `ClipCursor(NULL);`

Comment: Don't you mean `ClipCursor(NULL)` to release the cursor?  Or alternatively: `CRect prev_rect; GetClipCursor(&prev_rect); /* ... */ ClipCursor(&prev_rect);`